getting logout from my project without validating csrf token still using its middleware
I am getting  logout from current laravel project when i run below script on my browser with
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout" method="POST">  -here you can change the url of your logout route
    <!-- Removing the CSRF token from the form -->
    <!-- This will simulate a CSRF attack by submitting the request without the necessary token -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Request">
</form>

<script>
        document.forms[0].submit();
</script>  

Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('security')->name('logout');
i have applied middleware and printing its log but when i am running this script nothing got printed but my current user got logged out   i have also set same_site="strict"  also cors=['my domain'] but still getting logout

how your routing/middleware looks?
